# Allow Author role to publish one post type and not another

Tags: custom-post-types, permissions

I have two custom post types.  One of them, I would like the author role to be able to publish.  The other one, I would like for them to "Submit for Review".  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the post type is registered, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

one can specify custom 'capabilities'.  eg I have an events post type, with event as a base for the capabilities, so automatically, there is a matching set like the page/post capabilties.

Then one can use  justin tadlock's members plugin to assign capabilities to roles.   Assign 'create' but not 'publish' to the 'review' post type, but full rights to the other type.

Simple.

Comment: Thanks. I followed http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types and it worked great.