# How to restrict author to only access one custom post type ?

Tags: custom-post-types, users, author, capabilities

My installed Wordpress have 4 custom post type and 1 default post type. Basically what i want is that the author can also access particular one custom post type. Author must not see other post types.

Comment: Maybe this other topic will help: [Link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25601/allow-author-role-to-publish-one-post-type-and-not-another)

Answer (score 1):

As linked to in the other comment by @AXheladini; you will need to set up Roles and/or Capabilities. Once that is done use the function `current_user_can()` ([codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)) to allow or deny the actual page.